# Incorrect display of URLs in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

All the URLs in my rails app show both the URL text and the actual URL. So, for e.g., if I use [Hello](/test), the link shows up on the actual page as "Hello(/test)" instead of just "Hello".

https://skitch.com/e-felixjamestin/g64mi/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-home

Why is this? It seems like a simple enough thing to correct, but I've unable to find any info on this.

Do help :)

Answer (score 0):

follow the screenshot - it is or incorrect css or preferences of your browser. ( HTML is right )